# Trying to fix merge conflict by rebasing, change X closed

Tags: gerrit

I am currently trying to fix some merge conflicts that are coming up in Gerrit. I've tried to rebase and submit my commits manually from Gerrit, but it hasn't been working out. What I'm trying to do now is follow [this guide](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/intro-user.html#rebase) to rebase in order to fix the merge conflicts. Once I've manually fixed the merge conflicts in VScode, I try to push `temp-branch` with `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master`. It gets rejected with this message:

```
 ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/master (change <link to B> closed)
```

```
4e6b4ca (HEAD -> temp-branch) A
97bf4ds B
5392gsa (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) C
...
17sfv2t B
```

I'm assuming this problem is due to the fact that `17sfv2t B` has already been merged, but I'm not too sure. This is my first time with the rebasing process/Gerrit, so I might have missed some important details. Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right, the problem is due to the fact that the change with commit B is closed.

To solve this issue, first of all, you need to clarify why your "git log" has two B commits (97bf4ds a 17sfv2t) and how is possible to have a commit with a non-hexadecimal hash (17sfv2t), this is really weird.

It seems that the issue is related to commit 97bf4ds. Probably this commit has (by mistake) a Change-Id (a line in the commit description like, for example, "Change-Id: I0ff3092b7970f354df98c81a7d53f60ca826a55c") which is related to the closed change in Gerrit. Is this commit done by you? Why this commit has a Change-Id from a closed change?

Probably all you need to do is fix this Change-Id (using the "git rebase -i" command) before pushing the commits to Gerrit, but it's impossible to know for sure because you didn´t specify exactly what are you doing and what commands have you exactly executed to get in this situation.